# How to jump into REPL after the execution of a node.js script?

Tags: node.js

Is it possible with node.js to launch a script, wait for its completion (or an error), and then jump into the console, with access to the current environment variables?

When using python in general, you can add the -i flag to achieve this. Does the equivalent exist with node? If yes, how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `repl.start()` at the end of your code to do that.

```
const repl = require("repl");

const myVariable = 1;
console.log("myVariable: ", myVariable);
// provide extra contexts here to access in the REPL
repl.start().context.myVariable = myVariable;
```

Note that by default only global variables are accessible in the REPL. If you want to access other variables, you must pass them via `context`

`repl.start().context.yourVariable`

Read more in the [NodeJS document](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html#repl).